# I can't get page entry via Google Sites API if the page was not updated last 24 hours

Tags: java, google-api, google-sites

I'm using google sites api for java. I need to get all ListItemEntries in my site. I have following code:

```
ContentFeed contentFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(baseURL + domain + siteName), ContentFeed.class);
for (ListItemEntry entry : contentFeed.getEntries(ListItemEntry.class)) {
           for (Field field : entry.getFields()) {
                 System.out.println(field.getValue());
           }
}
```

It works perfect. But if ListItemEntry are not updated approximately for the last 24 hours, it doesn't find any ListItemEntry. The next blok returns nothing.

```
 service.getFeed(new URL(baseURL + domain + siteName), ContentFeed.class);
```

There is the same issue with ListPageEntry, may be and with other ContenEntry, I checked only for ListItemEntry and ListPageEntry.
Has anyone idea how resolve this issue?